# Get real URL for a POST operation

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to crawl a website which returns me a file to download by clicking a button. I'm trying to use Chrome debug tool only get this and couldn't not figure out how to restore a real URL behind the POST action:

Request Headers:

```
POST /download.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.rmdown.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 385
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.rmdown.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Referer: http://www.rmdown.com/link.php?hash=1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Request Payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ref"

1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reff"

MTM3OTQ4NzQwMQ==
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

download
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ--
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 07:35:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="3f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737.torrent"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 43428
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

Any idea?

Comment: Without any response data, there's nothing we can tell you

Comment: @Phil The response data has been added, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you make the POST request to (`http://www.rmdown.com/download.php`) *is* the real URL.

How the server determines what content to respond to a POST request to that URL with is internal to the server and opaque to the client.

Possibilities include:

- Reading data from a file on the server's hard disk
- Reading data from another URL
- Returning a Location header to send the client elsewhere (although it isn't in this case)
- Pulling half a dozen fields out of a database and putting them together using a template
- Randomly generating some bytes

Comment: The URL before I send POST action is: http://www.rmdown.com/link.php?hash=1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737, does the server ever collect that hash info?

Comment: It is sent to the server. Without having access to the code running on the server I can't tell if it is collected, processed and discarded or ignored.

Comment: So back to my original purpose, with referer link and this POST URL, how can I get the exact file download with HTTP request just like clicking the button?

Comment: You put the button in a form with suitable inputs.

Comment: But what if I want to do that in a script because I want to bulk download the site. I.e. only by specifying URL?